# How can i recover deleted pve/data correctly

Tags: lvm, proxmox

I accidentally deleted pve/data thin volume in proxmox. Very next second i realised this and i tried to recovering it as below

```
lvremove /dev/pve/data
ls -lrt /etc/lvm/archive
head /etc/lvm/archive/pve_00059-189435924.vg
vgcfgrestore pve --test -f /etc/lvm/archive/pve_00059-189435924.vg

  TEST MODE: Metadata will NOT be updated and volumes will not be (de)activated.
  Consider using option --force to restore Volume Group pve with thin volumes.
  Restore failed.
vgcfgrestore pve -f /etc/lvm/archive/pve_00059-189435924.vg --force
```

i thought it restored correctly, here is output

```
lvdisplay

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                data
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                xBjmdE-1l8m-LGM2-EC6g-MNrO-15O1-v6eaxb
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2018-09-12 21:21:59 +0530
  LV Pool metadata       data_tmeta
  LV Pool data           data_tdata
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                758.52 GiB
  Current LE             194181
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pve/data_meta0
  LV Name                data_meta0
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                TFIfYP-W54R-dPgd-8c1c-GQsv-uCRE-TmwfRl
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2018-09-12 21:21:59 +0530
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                7.74 GiB
  Current LE             1982
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pve/data_meta1
  LV Name                data_meta1
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                UUe3oN-HBjQ-bcua-TW2O-vEpL-k2Vc-MUdWeP
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2018-09-12 21:21:59 +0530
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                7.74 GiB
  Current LE             1982
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

But it is inactive and not usable at all. I can't create any VM in this space. It shows error

> ```
>   Using default stripesize 64.00 KiB.
>   Thin pool pve-data-tpool (253:4) transaction_id is 0, while expected 54.
> TASK ERROR: create failed - lvcreate 'pve/vm-107-disk-1' error:   Aborting. Failed to locally activate thin pool pve/data.
> ```

```
lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/swap' [8.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/root' [96.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/data' [758.52 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/data_meta0' [7.74 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/data_meta1' [7.74 GiB] inherit
```

I am trying to activate it but no success.

```
lvchange -a y pve/data

Thin pool pve-data-tpool (253:4) transaction_id is 0, while expected 54.
```

Can somebody help me to resolve this error.